# Which of these three prime lenses should I choose for my Canon 5D Mark II?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, canon-5d-mark-ii, digital

Which lens should I pick between the following, I'm after nice color / contrast:

- Leica 50mm f/2 Summicron-R
- Canon EF 50mm f/2.5 Macro
- Voigtländer 40mm f/2 Ultron SL II

Anyone with experience with these lenses?

Comment: Can you please give a little more background as to why you're considering these lenses in particular and what you're looking for?

Comment: Anyway, you forgot the 50mm sigma. Better then any of those mentioned above.

Comment: There is also a good 50mm f/1.4 and a very good 50mm f/1.2 L by Canon.

Comment: Maybe we should try to answer the question based off exactly what he asked - Which one of these three lenses has better color/contrast? I would give it a shot but I don't have experience with any of them.

Answer (score 6):

Leaving aside the image quality for the moment, you have some fundamental differences between the listed lenses:

- Canon 50mm f/2.5 - it's a native Canon lens, so you get autofocus and full exposure modes. You can get it new with warranty, and it's not expensive.
- Voigtländer 40mm f/2 - it has an EF mount but no autofocus. You'll get exposure automation, though. It's a pretty rare lens, and I don't know if it's available new with warranty. It's rather expensive for what it is.
- Leica 50mm f/2 R - you have to use this with an adapter. You don't get AF, and you have to meter stopped down. This lens is not available new. It's also expensive for a standard 50mm.

Comment: well thanks for your answers, but they're kind of not very useful.

Comment: @boon no-one other than yourself can answer the question "which lens should I pick" - all we can do is provide more information about the lenses so you can decide. Now the information posted here is about practical / mounting concerns, not image quality, but it may well be useful to other people who might read your question.